# ArcGis label last vertex Z value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, geometry

Is it possible to label a feature in ArcMap using geometry values?

In this instance I want to label features (polylines) with the *Live* Z value of the last vertex obtained from the *Shape*.

However when I try something simple like the XMin of the extent of the shape:

[image]

It returns an error:

[image]

Is it possible to use the features' geometry to formulate a label? I do not want to calculate values from the geometry into a field and then label that field unless I absolutely have to:

[image]

Ideally the label should be live, changing as the feature is modified.

Based on the answer by Felix:

```
def FindLabel ( [OBJECTID]  ):
  mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
  layers=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "WatrcrsL")
  lr=layers[0]
  with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lr, 'Shape@','OBJECTID = '+str( [OBJECTID] )) as cursor:
      for row in cursor:
         a=row[0].lastPoint.Z
  return a
```

Will label the features with the last points' Z value live!

Comment: Shoud be !Shape! in expession

Comment: You'd think @FelixIP.. just like the field calculator expression but I tried that and got a different error: Invalid syntax (<string>, line 1). You would also note that Shape doesn't appear in the list of fields to select (it's directly after OBJECTID).

Comment: I think being able to access the SHAPE@ tokens for writing label expressions would make a great ArcGIS Idea.

Comment: Me 2 @PolyGeo. You can declare cursors in a label expression same as in a field calculator expression so why not SHAPE@?

Comment: Yeah - my superficial understanding is that both label expressions and the field calculator run cursors in the background and in the case of the former it would already seem to be accessing its geometry to decide where to place the label.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Example for point layer

```
def FindLabel ( [FID] ):
  mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
  layers=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "ac_pipes_aspoints")
  lr=layers[0]
  with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lr, 'Shape@XY',r'"FID"='+str( [FID] )) as cursor:
      for row in cursor:
         a=row[0]
  return a[0]
```