# Spatial AND temporal join between two point data sets

Tags: arcgis-desktop, r, arcgis-10.3, spatial-join, date

I was hoping I could get some pointers in how to approach this issue, which is tricky version of a spatial join. I have been searching and I can't find a particular solution to what I need.

I have two data sets of **points** with related attributes that include **date** and **coordinates**. I want to join the points in data set A (records of events) with the nearest neighbor in the data set B (records of animal locations). The catch is that I want to **find a neighbor in B that is not only closest to A in space but also in time**. Perhaps explaining the purpose of this might help visualize what I want to do.

I want to join each event in A with the animal in B that was closest to the location of the event AND closest to the date in which the event happened. I have searched options with spatial join and "join by group" in ArcGIS. Yet I haven't been able to match according to attribute date given that the dates will not match exactly in every case. Thus, that is why I am looking for the record that is closest to that date instead of matching records that have equal dates and why I can't create fixed groups according to specific dates. Also I have a huge data set of about 100,000 records.

This is how my data bases look like. I have removed columns and rows to make it easier to visualize:

Database A, animal locations

```
indiv_code  sex month   year    Local_date  treatment   perturbati  xx  yy
A   M   3   2014    04-03-14    E   B   492533.82430000000  7935470.32100000000
A   M   2   2016    25-02-16    E   A   506713.28360000000  7938586.99800000000
A   M   2   2016    25-02-16    E   A   506732.55540000000  7938504.00800000000
B   M   2   2010    22-02-10    E   B   549766.00000000000  7909026.00000000000
B   M   2   2010    22-02-10    E   B   550720.00000000000  7908986.00000000000
B   M   2   2010    22-02-10    E   B   551746.00000000000  7906541.00000000000
B   M   1   2015    14-01-15    E   B   545292.81210000000  7891203.71800000000
B   M   1   2015    14-01-15    E   B   545292.82570000000  7891209.25100000000
B   M   1   2015    14-01-15    E   B   545262.86540000000  7891176.12900000000
C   M   4   2013    08-04-13    E   B   482280.00000000000  7941062.00000000000
C   M   4   2013    08-04-13    E   B   482266.00000000000  7941174.00000000000
C   M   4   2013    08-04-13    E   B   481805.00000000000  7942360.00000000000
```

Data base B, events

```
OID_    Dateincident    Year    Longitude   Latitude
1   10-01-08    2008    556517  7875861
2   15-01-08    2008    549887  7878550
3   15-01-08    2008    547800  7883200
4   17-01-08    2008    555500  7884500
5   30-01-08    2008    553530  7877180
6   31-01-08    2008    560328  7874984
7   31-01-08    2008    556517  7875861
8   01-02-08    2008    560400  7875900
9   01-02-08    2008    550400  7880500
10  01-02-08    2008    560500  7881500
11  01-02-08    2008    551800  7886800
13  14-02-08    2008    566300  7887700
14  20-02-08    2008    570326  7890088
15  27-03-08    2008    662271  7837444
```

I was thinking R could be the appropriate tool for this spatial and temporal join. Does anyone have any idea on how I could go about this? I have read so much information on spatial join, nearest neighbor and still can't figure this one out. If this is possible in ArcGIS, I have an advance licence for ArcGIS for Desktop.  If someone has an idea on how to do this in R and wants to help out, I can make a shorter sample of the data available to you.

Comment: Check this  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185673/arcgis-near-by-group/185718#185718  you need to modify query

Comment: Should be able to do it in either R or Arc (arcpy). Calculate distance and difference in time for all pairs (or a subset based on an upper limit). Then weight each (time and distance) to do an optimization for each event.

Comment: "Closest to the location" AND "closest to the date" usually has no solution.  To get any reasonable analysis done, you need to specify some kind of trade-off between distances in time and distances in space.

Comment: Thank you all for your insights! They will help me fine tune my intended analysis.

Comment: If you still need help with this, then please choose which of R and ArcGIS Desktop you wish to ask about in this particular question so that both the question and any answers can be focused on that.