# Setting python code to trigger on any update on feature class?

Tags: arcpy, coordinates, trigger

For example, when I have a geometry change on a point, I would like to update the X and Y fields to the new current location, I understand how to make the code, but not where do I set or put it to be triggered/called

Comment: are you asking how to set a field to update automatically when the point is moved without having to run a stand alone script to update it or use a field calculator?

Comment: looks like you can at least label the feature with dynamic text (http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011568), and apparently arc 9.3 had this functionality (http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Defining_a_Dynamic_attribute)

Comment: We schedule our updates, rather than having them trigger on edit. Have scheduled tasks run once a day (usually at night) to perform automatic updates.

Answer (score 2):

Use label expression:

```
def FindLabel ( [OID]  ):
  mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
  lr=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[0]
  with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(lr, ('Shape@','POINT_X','POINT_Y'),r'"OID"='+str( [OID] )) as cursor:
      for row in cursor:
         row[1]=row[0].firstPoint.X
         row[2]=row[0].firstPoint.Y
         cursor.updateRow(row)
  return '%i\n%i' %(int(row[1]),int(row[2]))
```

Comment: Nice! Using an existing event saves wiring a new one. Trust me FeatureModified triggers are a **pain** to work with - updating the feature with the new X and Y triggers the event then you go cyclic from there, after you've solved that the update of the X and Y becomes the last action so the Undo buffer is increased by one and the user can Undo the update (BAD). The more I think about it the more I like this solution.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson this is just a slight modification to this answer to your Q http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124398/arcgis-label-last-vertex-z-value/124402#124402