# ArcMap Label Expression using feature geometry

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I would like to label the X and Y coordinates without having to create a new field.    I have tried by using

```
!Shape.CENTROID.X!
```

but I get an error message "The expression contains and error."

I am using ArcMap 10.6, my data is in a geodatabase and I am using the python parser.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the parser you're using.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124398/arcgis-label-last-vertex-z-value/124402#124402

Comment: Nice example using Arcade, alas, in ArcGIS Pro: https://community.esri.com/thread/206955-how-can-i-get-xy-in-dec-degrees-from-a-poly-feat-serv-using-arcade