# Bearing Geometry Automatic Calculation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geometry, bearing, parcel-fabric

I am building a cadastral fabric and it's really nice to have the bearing and distance come up on the lines as I traverse around. I just found a great way to do this with the [Add Geometry ArcGIS tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-geometry-attributes.htm). It works most excellent:

[image: Cadastral Traverse]

But the issue I am having here is that the field does not auto-populate. I have rerun the Add Geometry tool everytime. Is there anyway to automate calculation? Its a pain to have to traverse a line and then run the tool.

Using the [answer of @FelixIP](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/311991/115), I was able to get it going, just add this into the label expression, set the parser to python and customise your attributes:

```
arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management(Input_Features="Cadastral Reference Lines", Geometry_Properties="LENGTH;LINE_BEARING", Length_Unit="FEET_US", Area_Unit="SQUARE_METERS", Coordinate_System="PROJCS['NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_17N',GEOGCS['GCS_North_American_1983',DATUM['D_North_American_1983',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',500000.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',0.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',-81.0],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.9996],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',0.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]]")
def FindLabel ([BEARING], [LENGTH]):
  return [BEARING] + " - " + [LENGTH] + "ft"
```

Comment: Something between this lines https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124398/arcgis-label-last-vertex-z-value/124402#124402

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments you can access most of the tools and Shape field from label expression:

```
lr="segments"
arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management(lr, "LINE_BEARING",  Coordinate_System="GEOGCS['GCS_NZGD_2000',DATUM['D_NZGD_2000',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]]")
def FindLabel ( [FID] ):
  with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lr,('Shape@',"Bearing"),r'"FID"='+str( [FID] )) as cursor:
      for shp, b in cursor:break
  L=shp.length;B=float(b)
  deg=int(B);mins=int((B-deg)*60)
  sec=int((((B-deg)*60)-mins)*60)
  return "{}<SUP>O</SUP>{}'{}'' - {:.2f} m".format(deg,mins,sec,L)
```

[image]

Comment: I ended up using a bit of yours (THANKS FOR THE HELP!!)